# AngularJS - Using ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use ui.router to wire up the routing of my app but I struggle with some problem.
I just to load the content of a div given a certain route but nothing appears.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body ng-app="twtApp">

    <div ui-view></div>


</body>


    <!-- bower:js -->    
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here is where I define my module:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('twtApp', [
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      // contributor
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<div><h1>Hello World!</h1></div>'
      });

  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to configure the `$urlRouteProvider` (which you've already injected) to include a default parameter:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
```

I believe your code would work if you put in the a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/#/
```

In that way, it would be explicitly hitting the '/' route that you've defined.

[More information on $urlRouteProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider)